# Auto Insert in another table MySQL without using trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have this two tables in MySQL that the PRIMARY KEY of table A is referenced in table B as FOREIGN KEY.

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `A_id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `x` int,
  `y` varchar(1024),
  `z` varchar(1024),
  PRIMARY KEY (`A_id`)
)



CREATE TABLE `B` (
  `B_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `A_id` int,
  `s` date,
  `e` date,
  PRIMARY KEY (`B_id`),
  KEY `A_id` (`A_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `B_constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`A_id`) REFERENCES `A` (`A_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

When INSERT into table A some records are automatically inserted into table B.

I tried SHOW TRIGGERS but no Triggers were defined in the Database.

I tried SHOW CREATE TABLE on the two tables but there is nothing special except for some CONSTRAINT of FOREIGN KEY on DELETE and UPDATE CASCADE.

Is there any other place this behavior can be defined? Or is there any way to avoid this when inserting into table A?

Comment: Is it at all possible you don't have rights to view the triggers?

Comment: I tried SELECT * FROM information_schema.TRIGGERS but there is still no data. I can still see other tables in information_schema, so it might not be the case?

Comment: howabout you post that show create table here? What is "some records" automatically inserted? Examples? Data?

Comment: Okay. For example, INSERT INTO A (x,y,z) VALUES (qq,ww,ee) would create a new record in A as (1, qq, ww, ee) and also in B like (`b_auto_increment_id_1`, 1, asd, ert); (`b_auto_increment_id_2`, 1, abc, def); (`b_auto_increment_id_3`, 1, xxx, zzz). The `b_auto_increment_id` are in a different range than when INSERT into B.

Comment: please edit your question to give table structure (show create table) for both

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you help me with this?

Comment: strange. You did that insert into A manually? Or through a software?

Comment: First I had this issue on PHP. But SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log doesn't show any INSERT INTO B. So I inserted into A manually and the same issue persists.